# Java String Split to implement a HashMap

Tags: java, string

I have a string in Java as follows, and I wanted to split it according to the following

```
String toSplit = "Apple,Fruit,10|Potato,Vegetable,15:Apple,Fruit,15|Potato,Vegetable,10|Banana,Fruit,10"
```

Basically, I wanted to have hashMaps from String to Integer, from the type (Apple/Banana) to their quantity (10/15) etc. I wanted to have one hashmap of this type until the ":" and one for after the ":" till the end of the string.

How do I go about splitting the string in a way that will allow me to implement the hashmap, and would I insert the stuff into the hashmap after splitting it?

Basically, the first part of the string (until ":") is the list of stuff I need to bought, with the quantity. And the second part of the string is the list of stuff I my target was. I need to output the difference in quantities of each.

I'm new to Java, so any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Show your expected output and what are your tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

First split on `:`, then on `|` and finally on `,` as shown below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String toSplit = "Apple,Fruit,10|Potato,Vegetable,15:Apple,Fruit,15|Potato,Vegetable,10|Banana,Fruit,10";
        List<Map<String, Integer>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Split on :
        String[] lists = toSplit.split(":");

        for (String list : lists) {
            // Split on |
            String[] records = list.split("\\|");

            Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (String record : records) {

                // Split on comma
                String[] parts = record.split(",");
                map.put(parts[0], Integer.valueOf(parts[2]));
            }

            arrayList.add(map);
        }
        System.out.println(arrayList);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[{Potato=15, Apple=10}, {Potato=10, Apple=15, Banana=10}]
```

Comment: No, *first* you split on `:`. Read the full question text for why, and don't change the input.

Comment: Thank you, but you missed the ":" in the string. I wanted to split the entire string in a similar way that you have shown, but one for before the ":" and one for after the ":"

Comment: @Andreas - Yes, I missed that. Correcting it.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Are you editing the answer?

Comment: Since `put()` needs an object, you should use [`Integer.valueOf(parts[2])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-), so the compiler doesn't have to generate the extra call to autobox the `int` returned by `parseInt`.

Comment: @Andreas - Thanks for yet another valuable suggestion. I've updated the answer to incorporate it.

Comment: The ArrayList is unnecessary and doesn't make sense in the context of the OPs problem.  They specifically want to compare 2 HashMaps (target vs actual).  Using an ArrayList is not only wasteful of resources, but it also allows for incorrect inputs.  If the user inputs a string with more than one `:`, the program should throw an exception, but your code will just add another element to the ArrayList.  I would just hardcode 2 HashMaps.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong - Thanks for the feedback. My aim was to simply guide the OP on how to split and process. I'll wait for OP's response and provide more help if needed.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong *"allows for incorrect inputs"* There is absolute no validation done in the code, so it obviously assumes valid input. If you want to check for invalid input, checking that it has exactly one `:` is the least of the problems. This is a valid example for handling the request in the question, and can be fine-tuned by OP as needed. Using an `ArrayList` allows this sample code to result in two maps, without repeating code and without writing methods.

Comment: I understand it was used as an example, and I don't expect the answer to perform any validation.  I think maybe my comment came across the wrong way.  I'm not trying to say there's anything wrong with this answer, I'm just suggesting that maybe an ArrayList isn't the tool that is best suited to this problem, and I was trying to show why that would be the case.